# How to fix OG tags facebook?

Tags: wordpress

I have spent the past couple of hour trying to figure out why the Facebook is not recognising the OG tags. I have always used yoast an have no problem but I ve tried the OG  plugin and that still hasnt helped.

The error Ive got from debugging is: The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

Every  OG tag checker is pulling in the meta dat bar facebook, this is the url in question: :https://mukai.co.uk/2020/03/24/google-estate-agent-platform/

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest you to check the page using http://validator.w3.org, there are some HTML errors  and facebook can have problems scanning your page.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.